# shell find command : Mixing excluding directories and including specific directories

Tags: shell, makefile, find

I'm faced with a directory structure like :

```
./xxx/src
./xxx/src/folder1
./xxx/src/folder2
./xxx/src/folder2/subfolder1
./xxx/UTest
./xxx/Module
./xxx/Itfs
./.hg
./Tools
```

Instead of having each module define it's own include search directory.  I want to find all relevant directories with a "simple" shell command and use this in my top level makefile.

That would look alot nicer and as bonus, force other users to use folders defined in the coding guidelines.

I got as far as  :

```
MODINCLUDES = \
$(shell find $(MODULE_DIR) \( -name .hg -o -name Tools \) -prune -o \( -name src -o -name Module -o -name Itfs  \) -type d -print| while read line; do echo "-I$$line"; done )
```

But this would result in

```
MODINCLUDES = -I/xxx/src -I/xxx/Module -I/xxx/Itfs
```

Obviously I would like have any subfolders in `src` to be included aswell.

```
./xxx/src/folder1
./xxx/src/folder2
./xxx/src/folder2/subfolder1
```

Can someone explain me, on how to do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, just don't restrict to just the three specific folders.  Take out the

```
\( -name src -o -name Module -o -name Itfs  \)
```

and maybe avoid the silly `while` loop if your `find` supports `-printf`:

```
MODINCLUDES = \
$(shell find $(MODULE_DIR) \
    \( -name .hg -o -name Tools \) -prune -o \
    -type d -printf "-I%p\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for the print switch.  Removing the sugested part, results in other folders like UTest to be included. I only want the subfolders in the folders named src, Itfs or Module.  I could add UTest to the prune statement to avoid this, but I would have to add allot of other directories in there.

Comment: Slap me silly... having multiple search paths does the job:  _find */src */Module */Itfs -type d -printf "-I%p\n"_

Comment: The wildcard there doesn't do what you think, `*/src` will find subdirectories named `src` within a directory immediately below, but not anywhere else.

Comment: It actualy finds subdirectories (src, Itfs and Module) and all other subdirectories of those 3, in each top level directory.  Wich is what i wanted.

Comment: The shell will expand the wildcard before `find` runs. So if you have `foo/src`, `bar/src`, and `baz/quux/src`, the command `find */src ...` will run `find foo/src bar/src ...` not `find foo/src bar/src baz/quux/src ...`

Comment: Yes I know, I woulnd't want baz/quux/src to print ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Finding the sub-directories you want with `find` can be done with:

```
find $(MODULE_DIR)/xxx/src $(MODULE_DIR)/xxx/Module $(MODULE_DIR)/xxx/Itfs -type d
```

And then, putting this in a Makefile and adding the `-I` prefix:

```
ROOTDIRS    := $(addprefix $(MODULE_DIR)/xxx/,src Module Itfs)
SUBDIRS     := $(shell find $(ROOTDIRS) -type d)
MODINCLUDES := $(addprefix -I,$(SUBDIRS))
```

Or, all at once:

```
MODINCLUDES := $(addprefix -I,$(shell find $(addprefix $(MODULE_DIR)/xxx/,src Module Itfs) -type d))
```